# Can we lock the entire worksheet without protecting using VBA excel code, not looking for Password Protection

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xr As Range
Dim xRgEx As Range
Dim xRgExEach As Range
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:N,1:15")
Set xRg = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M:Z,15:30") 'Change the row range and column range you will lock without protecting worksheet
Set xRgEx = Application.Intersect(xr, xRg)
If xRgEx Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Cells(1, 1).Select 'Specify a cell you will shift to after selecting the locked cells
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

and I know this is not right I have to make my worksheet non editable Range is L18 to AI 50

Comment: Please don't jam your whole question into the title - there's plenty of room in the body of the post to describe what the problem is.  If you want to make L18:AI50 non-editable then lock the cells in that range and protect the sheet (cells outside of that area should be unlocked if they need to remain editable)

Comment: but after doing this if  I select unprotect option from excel sheet tab ,than I am able to write  in given locked cells so how can I stop the sheet for being unprotected

Comment: We’ll you’d typically use a password but you said you don’t want that so…

Comment: Yes @TimWilliams so is there any way to achieve this

Comment: Why not use a password?

Comment: Password can be shared ,so the client does not want the easiest one @TimWilliams

Comment: I don't know of any alternative which would be more secure - it's pretty easy for anyone to look at your VBA, even if you password-protect the VB project.